# Reversing a String

Tags: c#, logic, reverse

I was just researching how can I reverse a String. I found a Program in C# The Complete Reference Book but i was not able to understand it. Plz anyone Explain me how it works

The Program is here:

```
using System;
class RevStr 
{
    // Display a string backward.
    public void DisplayRev(string str) 
    {
        if(str.Length > 0)
            DisplayRev(str.Substring(1, str.Length-1));
        else
            return;

        Console.Write(str[0]);
    }
}

class RevStrDemo 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        string s = "this is a test";
        RevStr rsOb = new RevStr();
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: " + s);
        Console.Write("Reversed string: ");
        rsOb.DisplayRev(s);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

1. How does this program works?
2. Does the statement `rsOb.DisplayRev(s);` call `DisplayRev(str.Substring(1, str.Length-1));` for every Character in the string?

Comment: It is an example of recursion. Presumably the book talks about recursion?

Comment: We will not explain the _whole_ program. Please tell us _exactly_ what you are not understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What I'd Recommend**

Have you tried `myString.Reverse();`

It would be the easiest way to reverse a string in C# (.Net 3.5 and above).

**Response**

As for your example it is using [`Recursion`](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Recursion) to display each character by removing the end character (by creating a substring of the original with the first char removed) then calling itself again until there are no characters remaining.

You will only need to call `DisplayRev(s);` once because it recursively displays each character within.

**Explanation Attempt**

For example we have the string `"hello"`.

The first call will recursively call the function with the `substring` of `"hello"` which will be `"ello"`

*Note that the call to the Console.WriteLine hasn't been made, because the function `DisplayRev` has been called so we then step in to the recursive call.*

This will keep on occuring until the string is empty (`.Length == 0`). Then the function will exit and return to the caller, which will be where the string[0] is "o", the `Console.WriteLine` code will be hit writing the "o" to the console, this function will then be exited and the caller of that will then hit the `Console.WriteLine`, which will be the "l", this will keep returning until the initial call is reached.

Thus resulting in your initial string, reversed.

**Reference**

There are a number of tutorials around about recursion. Here's a few (they'll be better at explaining it than I am):

[Recursion Example 1](http://csharpcomputing.com/Tutorials/Lesson21.htm)
[Recursion Example 2](http://www.dotnetperls.com/recursion)

Comment: Obviously this code is not an example of how to reverse a string. It's a demonstration of recursion! And yet the up-votes flow!

Comment: The crocodiles were out before I had chance to complete my answer today!

Answer (score 3):

No.

It uses **Recursive** calls

**DisplayRev** calls itself with one less char

when it get to the end , and **back** from the recursion - it prints the char.

Also notice that its just display the reveresed string and **not** actually revere it

Answer (score 1):

What is happening inside there in class.look carefully 
See there is Sub-string function is calling with two parameters.

1. is length of string[**here is only a char**]
2. position in string

   and then it print that char. and its a recursive call so it happens until string length is non zero.

Answer (score 1):

It's a recursive call to the same function.

Basically it relies on the fact that the `Console.Write` command isn't called until the previous call to `DisplayRev` has returned.

Each call to DisplayRev is passed a string that is has had the first character removed:
For

```
str = "abcdef"
str.Substring(1, str.Length-1)
```

gives `"bcdef"`

The Console command writes the first character (str[0]).

By the time that the last DisplayRev call is processed str[0] is "f".

All calls then wind back to the first call, with lots of displays e.g.:

```
Console.Write("f")
Console.Write("e")
Console.Write("d")
Console.Write("c")
Console.Write("b")
Console.Write("a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the built-in functionality of string?

```
string s =  "123";
s = s.Reverse();
```

Comment: The answer to that question is that @user is trying to learn about recursion

Answer (score 0):

This program simply outputs the string reversed, it does not modify the string in any way.
Here is how it works - it is based on recursion. If you print the reverse of the substring of the initial one starting at position 1(i.e. str.Substring(1, str.Length-1)) and then print the first character of the string you will end up with your whole string being reversed. Obviously the function is correct for strings of length 1 and after that you can prove using induction and the above observation that the given function will print the string reversed correctly for all lengths.

However there is a built-in function to reverse a string if you do not insist on implementing it yourself:

```
str.Reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a dry run:

> input string = "This is a test";

Recursive reverse function called:

```
public void DisplayRev(string str)      
{         
    if(str.Length > 0)             
        DisplayRev(str.Substring(1, str.Length-1));
    else
         return; 

    Console.Write(str[0]);     
}
```

Stack call with argument are as follows:

```
DisplayRev("t")             // ----> prints "t"

DisplayRev("st")            // ----> prints "s" ----> complete string "ts"

DisplayRev("est")           // ----> prints "e" ----> complete string "tse"

DisplayRev("test")          // ----> prints "t" ----> complete string "tset"

DisplayRev(" test")         // ----> prints " " ----> complete string "tset "

DisplayRev("a test")        // ----> prints "a" ----> complete string "tset a"

DisplayRev(" a test")       // ----> prints " " ----> complete string "tset a "

DisplayRev("s a test")      // ----> prints "s" ----> complete string "tset a s"

DisplayRev("is a test")     // ----> prints "i" ----> complete string "tset a si"

DisplayRev(" is a test")    // ----> prints " " ----> complete string "tset a si "

DisplayRev("s is a test")   // ----> prints "s" ----> complete string "tset a si s"

DisplayRev("is is a test")  // ----> prints "i" ----> complete string "tset a si si"

DisplayRev("his is a test") // ----> prints "h" ----> complete string "tset a si sih"

DisplayRev("This is a test")// ----> prints "t" ----> complete string "tset a si siht"
```

Answer (score 0):

Reversing a String (Most efficient algorithm) : The following does not deal with UTF-16 surrogate pairs.

```
public static String reverse(String orig){
   char[] s = orig.ToCharArray();
   int n = s.Length;
   int halfLength = n / 2;
   for (int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++){
     char temp = s[i];
     s[i] = s[n - 1 - i];
     s[n - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
    return new String(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people seem to want to do this… one neat way is to utilise Array.Reverse

Pass the string to a char array, use Array.Reverse then pass the char array back as a string.

```
Public static string ReverseString(string str)
{
char[] arr = str.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(arr);
return new string(arr);}
```